# Developing animated GUI on Windows

Tags: windows, user-interface, desktop-application

Is there any realisation of animated GUI for any language except Silverlight?

Something like jQuery animations in web applications.

Something without requiring the user to install anything before using application.

Thanks ;)

Comment: silverlight is not a language..

Comment: @BlackBear i mean animated interface. Animated popups, sliding tables, fade effects and so on.

Comment: @Beck: I was serious (though it doesn't seems like), perhaps some static texts on a moving sprite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specifically exclude Silverlight, though it's not clear whether that is only because it targets the Web or for other reasons, too.

If you're happy to develop against the .NET Framework (which these days should be installed on most recent Windows systems), you could look at **WPF** (Windows Presentation Foundation), which has many similarities to Silverlight (e.g. it's also based on XAML), but targets desktop applications.

Comment: It seems just what i needed. Does it have any disadvantages?

Comment: Nothing is perfect, so of course it has *some* disadvantages. It depends what you want to do. Just give it a try and see if it works fine enough for your purposes!